# In following not always true in Javascript code in the browser: this === window?

Tags: javascript, browser, webpack

I have an old JS app, for which I need to implement some new features.
Some of the old modules have been implemented like:

```
(function() {
  ...

  this.MyModule = MyModule;
}).call(this);
```

This worked fine.
Now I have to implement additional modules, and I would like to do this using react. I have updated my webpack configuration, and added 'es2015' to the presets for the babel loader:

```
{
  test: /(\.js|\.jsx)$/,
  exclude: /(node_modules)/,
  loader: 'babel',
  query: {
    presets: ['react', 'es2015']
  }
}
```

and now my original modules are not loaded any more.
And now I get the following error when I run my code in the browser:

```
MyModule.js:185 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'MyModule' of undefined
```

for this line of code:

```
this.MyModule = MyModule;
```

This looks to e as if in Javscript, this would not be window any more?
Can this be true?

If I remove the 'es2015' preset everything seems fine.

Can anybody provide me a hint?

Thanks,
Gerald

Comment: yes, it can, through the way the module-loader works and 'use strict'. If you use a module loader, use it's mechanics to export things, instead of attaching things to `window`. Besides that, there should be a variable `global` available now. Or you change `}).call(this)` to `})()`.

Comment: @Thomas Ok, Thanks for the hint.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up solving this by using different webpack loader definitions: a loader for my old files, where I do not need the 'es2015' preset and another loader for my new files where I use the 'es2015' presets.